# How to support push notification in Capacitor with websocket for my chat app

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, push-notification, capacitor

I'm not finding any correct solution to implement push notification with websocket.

My simple requirement like WhatsApp chat when a message comes it show the message in the form of push notification.

[Here is the documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/push-notifications) for push notification.

```js
/**
 *  Push notification code
*/


import { PushNotifications } from '@capacitor/push-notifications';

const addListeners = async () => {
  await PushNotifications.addListener('registration', token => {
    console.info('Registration token: ', token.value);
  });

  await PushNotifications.addListener('registrationError', err => {
    console.error('Registration error: ', err.error);
  });

  await PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationReceived', notification => {
    console.log('Push notification received: ', notification);
  });

  await PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationActionPerformed', notification => {
    console.log('Push notification action performed', notification.actionId, notification.inputValue);
  });
}

const registerNotifications = async () => {
  let permStatus = await PushNotifications.checkPermissions();

  if (permStatus.receive === 'prompt') {
    permStatus = await PushNotifications.requestPermissions();
  }

  if (permStatus.receive !== 'granted') {
    throw new Error('User denied permissions!');
  }

  await PushNotifications.register();
}

const getDeliveredNotifications = async () => {
  const notificationList = await PushNotifications.getDeliveredNotifications();
  console.log('delivered notifications', notificationList);


/**
   Web Socket related code
*/

// Create WebSocket connection.
const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");

// Connection opened
socket.addEventListener("open", (event) => {
  socket.send("Hello Server!");
});

// Listen for messages
socket.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  console.log("Message from server ", event.data);
  PushNotifications.send("Message from server ", event.data);  // added for testing but does not work
});

}
```

Comment: any pointers or reference is most welcomed !

Comment: Please see: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend not using websocket for push notifications since websocket takes a lot of resources. also you cannot keep it up when your application is in background, the phone's OS probably restrict your app's activity when it is not in foreground. I suggest using the capacitor plugins such as [Capacitor Push Notification](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/push-notifications). these plugins use underlying methods provided by the OS.

Furthermore, if you're working with web-based solutions, developing a TLS websocket connection might be challenging. Webviews typically don't provide direct access to such low-level functionality. You need to implement native solutions if you want to go with websockets eventually.

Comment: Actually all our notifications are based on websocket it will be huge change.  so my question is i want to use **Capicator push notification alog with Websocket**

Comment: @EaBengaluru Not a good idea.

Comment: @EaBengaluru they are not compatible. try the plugins, if they don't solve your problem completely without using websockets, then ask again about the exact problems you are having.

Comment: mine is chat app and websocket is required actually.

Comment: @EaBengaluru only when the user is in the chat page, not when the app is minimized. when the user is in page you don't need notifications. check out apps like Telegram, almost the best in chatting app product. their chatting system is totally different from push notifications.

Comment: @AmirAliSaghaei  whatever the reason could be but i want push notification with websocket and for that i have reffered Slack.

Comment: @EaBengaluru if your app is only native (and not web), I'd suggest developing native websockets (in kotlin and/or swift) with capacitor plugins. I don't know how, and I'm not even sure TLS websocket in Ionic web is feasible. and if you use regular websockets instead of TLS, your app would be vulnerable to security risks.